# Synchronized commit on AAG ON not working in sql 2006 realtime

Tags: availability-groups

/*my always on availability group is Synchronized commit mood. this is two node. in sql query editor i just insert a record in primary node db and next sql query to select that data from readonly secondary node. it shows nothing. but after withing a sec. select query return the result. how can i make sure that the commit acknowledgement from read only db is done before querying the next statement ??????

Comment: You have to understand  - that this is a Q&A site ran by the community for the community. People **at-will** and without any money are helping you. So it **might be urgent for you** but not for the people spending valuable time. Spend some time and have a look at [help on asking good questions](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer: Don't try to. If you app requires that logic then AGs aren't for you.